# An "A" keeps getting added to the beginning of a multidimensional array when I add a new array. Any idea on what's causing this?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an odd issue. I have a multidimensional array in an SQL database. I add additional arrays into the array on a weekly basis via cron job. It works well for the most part but sometimes a random `A` gets added to the array when a new array is added. Does anyone have any idea as to what can cause this? It makes the `json_decode` result `null` when fetched.

Here is what the clean array looks like in the database after a new item has been added:

```
{"UCUVa51UA_690sEKyRbHb-5A":{"1":"1816468"},"UCfagwFCjnHBYRYIyBnmNAdA":{"1":"39839"}}
```

Here is what randomly happens sometimes a new item is added:

```
A"UCUVa51UA_690sEKyRbHb-5A":{"1":"64,596"},"UCfagwFCjnHBYRYIyBnmNAdA":{"1":"16,756"},"UCk2KE7yg0BwsJfr8Dp9ivUQ":{"1":"175,859"}}
```

It's a bit frustrating. Here is the snippet of script that adds the new array to the existing one:

```
foreach( $request['author_channel'] as $key => $value ){
        if ($value['platform'] == 'Youtube' || $value['platform'] == 'youtube'){
            $channelidtwo=$value['channel'];

            //converting channel id to url
            $mainchannelid=$value['channel'];
            $link=$request['author_channel'][$key]['channellink'];
            //this is where we're messing up
            $request['author_channel'][$key]['channellink']="https://www.youtube.com/channel/".$channelidtwo;
            $channelid=array('id' => $value['channel']);
            // $channelid=array('id' => 'UCdHUJoh8Si5V88m4ObkS7FA');
            //running hardy's function on the id of the channel
            $subscribers=subscribersById($channelid);
            //running hardy's function on the id of the channel
            $title=titleById($channelid);

            $avgviews=addavgviews($channelidtwo);

            $avgviews=number_format($avgviews);

            $request['author_channel'][$key]['channelname'] = $title;


            $request['author_channel'][$key]['subscribers'] = number_format($subscribers);
            if( !empty($subscribers) ){
                $request['author_channel'][$key]['subscriber'] = number_format($subscribers);
            }
            if( !empty($title) ){
                $request['author_channel'][$key]['channelname'] = $title;
            // update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'channel_video', $request['author_channel'] );
            }

            $currentyoutube=get_post_meta($result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', true );
            if (empty($currentyoutube)){
                $channelid=$value['channel'];
                $newyoutubearray=array($channelid=>array('1'=>$subscribers));
                $newyoutubearray= utf8_encode(json_encode($newyoutubearray,true));
                update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', $newyoutubearray );
            }else{
                $viewarray=json_decode($currentyoutube,true);
                $channelid=$mainchannelid;
                $addyoutubearray=array('1'=>$subscribers);
                foreach ($viewarray as $key=> $value){
                    if ($key !==$channelid){
                        $viewarray[$channelid]=$addyoutubearray;
                        $viewarray= utf8_encode(json_encode($viewarray,true));
                        update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', $viewarray );        
                    }
                }    
            }
```

I apologize for my poor style, I'm newer to web development. If there is any other information you need please let me know. Thank you for the help!

**update- so this "A" only happens when the third item is added to the array. Not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: Smells like a non escaped string.

Comment: My hunch is that this is a character encoding issue. Make sure your database connection is with utf-8 encoding, that your script files are saved in utf-8 encoding, ...etc. Make *everything* utf-8. When `json_decode` returns null, make sure to read the error reason with `json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: I'll test that, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @Tyr the channel id array that caused this was "UCk2KE7yg0BwsJfr8Dp9ivUQ". It's adding the "A" at the beginning of the array however. Any way to confirm is this is an escaping issue?

Comment: Try removing the `true` parameter on the `json_encode` call. The second parameter is a bitmask through several options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I removed the true parameter and it still added the "A" when I added the third item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Providing the answer here in case anyone ever encounters the same problem.

I really appreciate the answers to help solve the issue as well.

Here is the updated code that worked:

```
    foreach( $request['author_channel'] as $key => $value ){
        $platform=$value['platform'];
        if ($platform == 'Youtube' || $platform == 'youtube'){
            $channelidtwo=$value['channel'];

            //converting channel id to url
            $mainchannelid=$value['channel'];
            $link=$request['author_channel'][$key]['channellink'];
            $request['author_channel'][$key]['channelid']= $channelidtwo;
            $request['author_channel'][$key]['channellink']="https://www.youtube.com/channel/".$channelidtwo;
            $channelid=array('id' => $value['channel']);

            //running youtube functions on the id of the channel
            $subscribers=subscribersById($channelid);
            $totalviews=totalviews($channelid);
            $totalvideos=getvideocount($channelid);
            $title=titleById($channelid);                
            $avgviews=addavgviews($channelidtwo);

            $request['author_channel'][$key]['channelname'] = $title;

            $request['author_channel'][$key]['subscribers'] = ($subscribers);
            if( !empty($subscribers) ){
                $request['author_channel'][$key]['subscriber'] = ($subscribers);
            }
            if( !empty($title) ){
                $request['author_channel'][$key]['channelname'] = $title;
             update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'channel_video', $request['author_channel'] );
            }

            $currentyoutube=get_post_meta($result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', true );
            if (empty($currentyoutube)){
                $channelid=$mainchannelid;
                $newyoutubearray=array($channelid=>array('1'=>$subscribers));
                $newyoutubearray= json_encode($newyoutubearray);
                update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', $newyoutubearray );
            }else{
                $viewarray=json_decode($currentyoutube,true);

                //here's what I added to obtain array keys and insert multidimensional array without alter key syntax
                //I commented out the incorrect foreach key test below to show the difference
                $viewChannelIds = array_keys($viewarray);

                $channelid=$mainchannelid;
                $addyoutubearray=array('1'=>$subscribers);
                if( !in_array( $channelid, $viewChannelIds ) ){
                    $viewarray[$channelid]=$addyoutubearray;
                    $viewarray=json_encode($viewarray);
                    update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', $viewarray );        
                }
                /*foreach ($viewarray as $key => $value){
                    if ($key != $channelid){
                        $viewarray[$channelid]=$addyoutubearray;
                        if (mb_substr($viewarray,0,2)=='"a'){
                            $viewarray=substr($viewarray,2);
                        }
                        $viewarray=json_encode($viewarray);
                        echo $viewarray;
                        //update_post_meta( $result->ID, 'youtube_subscribers', $viewarray );        
                    }
                } */   
            }
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain in your answer what caused the problem and what specifically you had to change to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The following is wrong:

```
$viewarray= utf8_encode(json_encode($viewarray,true));
```

You should not call `utf8_encode` on anything that is *already* utf-8 encoded. The output of `json_encode` is supposed to be `utf-8`, as it requires its argument to be `utf-8`.

In fact, calling `utf8_encode` can damage a valid string if it already has a multibyte encoding.

Besides that, make sure that your database is `utf-8` (or similar) encoded, and your database connection is `uft-8` encoded, ...etc.

When `json_decode` returns `null` be sure to check the string returned by [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php).

Comment: So make viewarray this: $viewarray=json_encode($viewarray,true);  ?

Comment: The db row is set to utf8, could it be the longtext? Here is an image of the row for this array. It's set in meta value. https://imgur.com/a/zjic1

Comment: Yes, don't call `utf8_encode`. The database fields have the correct encoding. You could also check whether you connection from PHP is using `utf-8`, but it is quite likely the `utf8_encode` made you write corrupt strings to the database (which will still be there).

Comment: I removed all of the utf-8 encodes and am still encountering the same issue whenever the 3rd item is added into the array.

Comment: Do you see the "A" also when printing `$viewarray` (debugging with `echo`) just before you call `update_post_meta`?

Comment: No I did not but I appreciate your input on cleaning up a lot of my syntax. I updated/cleaned all of my files per your input. ]